# Suspcious yam, xmr, miner process running on AWS server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, server

Sudden AWS servers went busy w/ 1 or more instances of process running: ./yam -c 1 -M stratum+tcp://binyu.crypto%40gmail.com:x@xmr.pool.minergate.com:45660/xmr.  This minergate is some "Cryptocurrency GUI miner", so this is alarmning.  I have killed the processes.  But cannot locate such like Are my servers hacked and being used as some online currency server?

Comment: Try taking a look in /var/lib/redis/, we've found a script there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my AWS server... I think they somehow got in through redis.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly got same thing.

They also somehow got from redis. In fact redis was behind firewall. Have no idea how they do that.

Had to reinstall OS suggest the same thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use JSF Primefaces? This sounds like a prime faces injection attack in which they terminate an input field with  then follow with the input that allows them to gain root access.

Check for injection by:
grep -n "&cmd=cd+" /etc/httpd/logs/[whatever-your-log-file-name-is]

You will be able to see command by command the attack.

You may want to at the very least inoculate yourself from those ISP's that host these animals using your firewall.